# Missing disclosure triangle when using the <summary> tag

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I'm having trouble with the <summary> tag. My problem is in Jupyter Notebook but it's reproducible [here](http://markdown-it.github.io/).

When I have the following in a markdown cell:

```
<details>
    <summary>Dropdown label</summary>
Hidden text
</details>
```

The result I get is "Dropdown label". Clicking on the words will expand to show "Hidden text" as expected, the problem is that there's no disclosure triangle to alert the user that it's a dropdown.

If I change it to this:

```
<details>

    <summary>Dropdown label</summary>
Hidden text
</details>
```

It shows the disclosure triangle, but it says "Details", and the <summary> is part of the collapsed text.

How can I get it to display both the correct label *and* the disclosure triangle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Normalize.less styles are removing the triangle

It took me a moment to realize. The disclosure triangle is actually a list style. The `Normalize` css file that site is including, changes `<summary>` to display as a block, which removes any list styling. Make sure the summary tag is `display: list-item` and not block.

#### Complete Code-

```html
<details>
    <summary style="display:list-item">Dropdown label</summary>
Hidden text
</details>
```

Comment: I edited your answer because a markup newbie like me had trouble figuring out how to actually implement it in code.